# Image located on page in div with id instead of src - Wrap an image around a cylindrical object in HTML5 / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an image to wrap around a cylinder, thanks to a previous post.

Having trouble trying to wrap a base64 image around the cylinder.

The image is located within a div with an id of #nbdesigner_frontend_area img that is already on the page instead of an external src image file.

Trying to change img.src to a base64 image already on the page in a div id.

Any suggestions? I know I'm close. Full code on fiddle...

```
function loadUpperIMage() {
var img = new Image();


img.src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/pussyhunter/image/upload/v1488184107/500_F_97150423_M13q2FeAUZxxIx6CaPixHupprmyiVVli_skh6fe.jpg"
img.onload = function() {

  var iw = img.width;
  var ih = img.height;

  var xOffset = 102, //left padding
    yOffset = 110; //top padding

  //alert(ih)
  var a = 75.0; //image width
  var b = 10; //round ness

  var scaleFactor = iw / (4 * a);

  // draw vertical slices
  for (var X = 0; X < iw; X += 1) {
    var y = b / a * Math.sqrt(a * a - (X - a) * (X - a)); // ellipsis equation
    ctx.drawImage(img, X * scaleFactor, 0, iw / 9, ih, X + xOffset, y + yOffset, 1, 174);
  }
};
}

};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n1r7dxnf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, the image has a parent element with the id `nbdesigner_frontend_area` - this solution is based on that assumption.

You can simply reference the `.src` of the element, so instead of something like this:

```
img.src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/pussyhunter/image/upload/v1488184107/500_F_97150423_M13q2FeAUZxxIx6CaPixHupprmyiVVli_skh6fe.jpg"
```

...do this:

```
var wrapImage = document.getElementById("nbdesigner_frontend_area").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
img.src = wrapImage.src;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in the fiddle, thank you. Only issue is, in the actual environment the source image appears in the div with the id well after the page loads, so when it runs onload it doesn't work. `img.onload = function() {` Thinking I need an if statement to check if the source image is present and it will run once the source image appears and not on page load. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thought this would work, but not dice `wrapImage.onload = function() {` didn't throw any errors, but it did't work in the fiddle

Comment: @user2059376 Could you describe the use case, i.e. what actions are taken by the user? I'm guessing you have an interface with the three mugs showing, and an area where the user can upload a file, and then you want it to wrap around the existing mug images. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. There is a div that is clicked as a button that opens the lightbox. The div has unique no id or class but it does have `data-action="preview-lightbox" data-defaulttext="Preview"` as a possible target. This could be used as a button to call the script, since the base64 image for the mugs is generated then. Any idea how to target do-action=preview-lightbox to run the script?https://jsfiddle.net/L5hc95kw/

Comment: If you can guarantee that it's the only div with that attribute and value, then you can use `document.querySelector('div[data-action="preview-lightbox"]');`, otherwise you can use `document.querySelectorAll('div[data-action="preview-lightbox"]');` and iterate through that until you find the right one.